# Floating image sticking out of bottom of div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have an image with css "float" set to "left", inside a "div" element. Even though the position is relative, the image does not force the height of the div to increase, and thus the image sticks out over the bottom of the div. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Set the *overflow* property for div to *hidden* or *auto*.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: +1 because I didn't know there was a new solution that didn't require a clearing div.